# ASP.NET Core Entity Framework identity discriminator cannot be NULL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, identity, discriminator

I'm moving an application from ASP.NET to Core is driving me nuts. A discriminator column has been added to the `AspNetUsers` table. The app is using EF Core 5 code first and I understand this has something to do with Table Inheritance which we do not want.

Well this is really nasty as can not access the property from my controller as it seems to want to be the calling class (`ApplicationUser`)  or even set the SQL type to 'allow NULL'.

Comment: *The app is using EF 5* - do you mean the "old" legacy EF v5 running on the full, classic .NET framework - or are you talking about EF **Core** v5 on .NET 5 ?

Comment: sorry EF Core v5 on .NET 5

Comment: actually I was able to force the column to allow nulls. my goal is to get rid of the column

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the Discriminator value? The `discriminator` column is used internally by Code First and you cannnot read/write its values from an inheritance mapping standpoint. To access the `discriminator` I would have to execute a SqlQuery against the database or change my mapping strategy. Reference [Table per Hierarchy (TPH)](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph#7667933)

Comment: the existance of this column is  pain that I would like to avoid dealing with as it throws an exception in my code that adds a new user to the Identity database . IdentityResult result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);.If i cannot set the property then what action  is supposed to.  This does not happen in old ASP.NET ! by allowing the column to be null is a partial solution but the exception tells me something is very wrong.   I notice you are a Nova Scotian?

Comment: Hi @JohnMcfetridge, can't reproduce the problem on my side, I have create a new Asp.net 5 application and add the discriminator column, the AspNetUser table definition [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdldQ.png), then, when using UserManager to create user, there is no need to add the discriminator column by myself, it will auto set the value in the database ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlsgB.png)). So, can you create a new sample to reproduce the problem and share with us via github or onedrive, so that we can work together to figure it out.